# Ganglia private page

Tags: .htaccess, ganglia

I have read the Ganglia documentation about authorization systems (https://github.com/ganglia/ganglia-web/wiki/Authorization-System).

I would like to restrict all access to the page via htaccess so only authenticated users could access it.

Would a .htaccess file with "Require valid user" on the ganglia web be enough?